# Bounded sequence of functions implies convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

Here you can see my attempt at the proof. I am sure I did something wrong because my prof asked me to show it for rationals and I "somehow" showed it for all reals. I would appreciate it if someone can spot my mistake! Thanks

The reference to the theorem 3.6 is for Rudin "Principles of Mathematical Analysis":

Theorem 3.6:
If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space X, then some subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point of X

[image: my attempt at the proof]

Comment: 1. Theorem 3.6 guarantees the existence of "some" subsequence, but when you apply it in your solution you say "each" subsequence. 2. More importantly, you need to pick a subsequence $n_k$ such that the claim holds simultaneously for any rational $x$. if you [correctly] apply Theorem 3.6, the subsequence you get for one $x$ might be different from the subsequence you get for a different $x$.

Comment: Consider carefully the difference between the statements "for every $x$ there exists a subsequence..." and "there exists a subsequence such that for every $x$..."  You have proved the first one, but you were supposed to prove the second, which is harder.

Comment: @NateEldredge my bad. makes a lot of sense!!

Comment: @angryavian thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose a subsequence working for only one $x$. There is zero guarantee that this same subsequence will work for another.

More precisely, your compactness argument is as follows:

Let $x$ be a real number. The sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is bounded, thus there exists an increasing $\varphi_x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $(f_{\varphi_x(n)}(x))_n$ is convergent.

But if $y$ is another real number, there is no reason why $(f_{\varphi_x(n)}(y))_n$ is convergent.

Comment: isn't the argument valid for any x in the domain [a,b]?

Comment: Yes, but: « for every $x$ there exists a subsequence that works » does not imply « there exists a subsequence that works for every $x$ ». It is the same reason why, say: « for each human being, there exists a scalar that is their age » holds, but « there exists a scalar such that, for each human being, said scalar is their age » does not.

Comment: thanks. understood! i'll accept your answer when i can